# Ecommerce or e-commerce?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We currently have both an [ecommerce](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecommerce) and an [e-commerce](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e-commerce) tags. Which should we keep?

I personally prefer [e-commerce](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e-commerce) and that's the spelling used in the [Merriam-Webster dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ecommerce), but it only has 4 questions (3 of which are closed) whereas [ecommerce](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecommerce) has 16 questions.

We typically set up synonyms from smaller tags to larger, but in this case both are pretty small and it wouldn't be a big deal to make either one a synonym of the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [AP Stylebook](http://www.apstylebook.com/?do=ask_faq), the [Chicago Manual of Style](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/does-ebook-have-a-hyphen.aspx), [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/e-commerce), and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-commerce) all use "e-commerce." The places where I've seen "ecommerce" being acceptable also list "e-commerce" as an acceptable construction (for example, [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/e-commerce)).

It looks like only "email" has been able to shed its hyphen elsewhere (e.g. the AP Stylebook): I'd say we continue to follow the convention and use [e-commerce](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e-commerce).

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd go for [e-commerce](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e-commerce) as the master with the synonym being [ecommerce](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecommerce).

However, by the same logic we should also make sure that [e-mail](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e-mail) is the master and [email](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email) the synonym too if we want to be consistent. However these stand at 0 and 24 questions respectively and on Stack Overflow [email](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/email/synonyms) (no hyphen) is the master. So if we check what Stack Overflow does with e-commerce we see that [e-commerce](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/e-commerce/synonyms) is the master.

So, there doesn't seem to be a network standard at all! However, perhaps we should go with consistency at the individual tag level.

Comment: I could be mistaken, but it looks to me that [e-commerce](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/e-commerce) is the master and ecommerce is the synonym: "The following tags will be remapped to e-commerce: 
ecommerce"

Comment: @MarkTrapp - you're right. I misread that page. So - there's a lack of consistency on Stack Overflow...